# checking isset at bottom of page not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dilemma (which I am yet to find a way around). For some reason, **PHP** doesn't want to check if `$_POST["login"]` at the bottom of the `<body>` tag within my document.

It will work if it is put at the very top of the document, or even the top of the `<body>` tag. However, if I put it at the top of the document / `<body>` tag, the output **JavaScript** will not execute!

For example, this is the document (where the **PHP** will not execute):

```
<form>
    <span id="example-element">Displaying.</span>
    <input type="text" name="example">
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["login"])){
        echo "
        <script>
            document.getElementById('example-element').style.display = 'block';
        </script>"
    }
?>
```

If I am to do something like this, however (the **PHP** will execute):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["login"])){
        echo "
        <script>
            document.getElementById('example-element').style.display = 'block';
        </script>"
    }
?>
<form>
    <span id="example-element">Displaying.</span>
    <input type="text" name="example">
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

But due to how **JavaScript** compiles, it will throw an error saying how it cannot set a style on a `null` element.

I have no idea how to get around this dilemma, so all help is appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: `<span id="example-element" style="<?php if isset($_POST['login']) echo 'display: block'; ?>">Displaying.</span>` - Styling the display using Javascript wouldn't be required, PHP can take care of it. An assumption here is that `$_POST["login"]` actually contains something. However, if a variable is indeed set at the start of the script, and is not tweaked during the execution, it should still be set towards the end of the script.

Comment: I agree with Dhruv Saxena, no js is necessary.  `<?php if(isset($_POST['login'])){echo "<span id=\"example-element\">Displaying.</span>";}?>`

Comment: Also if you want to show and hide from PHP, why not show and hide from PHP? `<? if ..... {?><span id="example-element">Displaying.</span><? } ?>`

Comment: Actually, In my case **JS** very much is necessary. I've just shrunk the **PHP** down so much that I'm only showing you what is necessary

Comment: Well, the idea is JS isn't required for setting the `display` property of the element in question if the only check needed is `isset($_POST['login'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form>
    <span id="example-element">Displaying.</span>
    <input type="text" name="example">
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET["login"])){
        echo "<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
             document.getElementById('example-element').style.display = 'block';
        }, false);           
        </script>";
    }
?>
```

Check if this works..... I've added the display code inside the `DOMContentLoaded` event and change the `$_POST` variable to `$_GET`. Works fine in my local system.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
<style>
.someClass {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["login"])){
        $hasClass = true;
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <span id="example-element" class=<?php if(isset($hasClass)==true) echo "someClass"; ?> >Displaying.</span>
    <input type="text" name="example">
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

The other problem with your code is that you are not setting method of your form and by default it is `GET` where as in php you were looking for `POST` request.
You could solve it either by using `$_REQUEST` in php when you are not sure about the method.

Answer (score 0):

Actally php executes before javascript.

Change like this

```
    <script>
        var isSubmit = "<?php isset($_POST['login'])?true:false; ?>";
        if(isSubmit){
        document.getElementById('example-element').style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>"
```